# Apply all IEntityTypeConfiguration derived classes in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Does anyone know of a way or have an implementation to apply ALL classes that derive from `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` to the `DbContext` at runtime?

There doesn't seem to be anything built in and loading each one manually via:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Table1Config())
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Table2Config())
    ...
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TableNConfig())
}
```

is going to prove rather tedious for a database with many tables.

Answer (score 13):

### For EF Core 2.2 and above:

From `EF Core 2.2` you don't need to write any custom extension method. `EF Core 2.2` added `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` extension method for this purpose. You can just use it as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly); // Here UseConfiguration is any IEntityTypeConfiguration
}
```

### For EF Core 2.1 or below:

You can write an extension method as follows:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyAllConfigurations(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
            .Any(gi => gi.IsGenericType && gi.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>))).ToList();

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(configurationInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is now built in to EF Core 2.2:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(PersonConfiguration).Assembly);
}
```

Comment: This looks working fine for the configuration. But when I have the independent seed class, it is not considering for the migration. Appreciate if someone could help to resolve


public class CountryDataSeed : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
    {
        var countries = new[]
        {
            new Country()
            {
                Name = "India"
                , IsActive = true
            }
        };

        builder.HasData(countries);
    }
}

Answer (score 4):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var implementedConfigTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract
            && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition
            && t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i =>
                i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>)));

    foreach (var configType in implementedConfigTypes)
    {
        dynamic config = Activator.CreateInstance(configType);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(config)` doesn't accept an `object`. It is looking for an instance of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`.