# EF Core is creating table from abstract class

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

While working on a Asp.Net Core Web Api I tried to make my Domain Model as DRY as possible.Therefore I first followed [this link](https://cpratt.co/generic-entity-base-class/) to create a Base Entity with all the Fields I knew I would need in my Application (I pretty much pasted the code so I am not going to paste it here again). After working a little more I wanted to add File Uploading to my project. To Realize that I created two Classes called Photo and TextFile:

```
    public class TextFile : File
        {
            #region Members
            /// <summary>
            /// The ForeignKey to the User
            /// </summary>
            public Guid UserId { get; private set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// The NavigationProperty to the User that added this Photo.
            /// </summary>
            public virtual User User { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region Constructors
            /// <summary>
            /// For Ef Core
            /// </summary>
            private TextFile()
            { }

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a new Instance of a TextFile.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="userId">The Id of the User that created this TextFile</param>
            public TextFile(Guid userId)
            {
                UserId = userId;
            }
            #endregion
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a Photo that got Uploaded
        /// </summary>
        public class Photo : File
        {
            #region Members
            /// <summary>
            /// Determines where this Image gets shown.
            /// </summary>
            public ImageOption? Option { get; private set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// The ForeignKey to the User
            /// </summary>
            public Guid UserId { get; private set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// The NavigationProperty to the User that added this Photo.
            /// </summary>
            public virtual User User { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region Constructors
            /// <summary>
            /// For EF Core
            /// </summary>
            private Photo()
            { }

            /// <summary>
            /// Basic Constructor
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="userId"></param>
            public Photo(Guid userId)
            {
                UserId = userId;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Methods
            /// <summary>
            /// Sets the Image Option only once
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="option"></param>
            public void SetImageOption(ImageOption option)
            {
                if (Option.HasValue)
                    return;
                else
                    Option = option;
            }      
            #endregion

        }
```

Here I created a abstract class called File because I wanted to avoid repeating myself with the same Fields and Methods.The File class inherits from Entity (from the article above) and has common Fiels like FileName and Filesize:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Base Class for all Files
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class File : Entity<Guid>
    {
        #region Members
        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the File
        /// </summary>
        public string FileName { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Path to the File
        /// </summary>
        public string FilePath { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Size of the File
        /// </summary>
        public int FileSize { get; private set; }

        public FileExtension Extension { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Text File to be uploaded to the Database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">The File to be Uploaded</param>
        /// <param name="relativeFolderPath">The Relative Path from the WebRoot.</param>
        /// <param name="userId">A UserId</param>
        /// <param name="extension">The Extension of this File.</param>
        /// <param name="token">A CancellationToken</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static File CreateTextFile(IFormFile file, string relativeFolderPath, Guid userId, FileExtension extension, CancellationToken token)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var textFile = new TextFile(userId);
            textFile.SetFileProperties(file, relativeFolderPath, extension, token);

            return textFile;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Image File Model
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">The File to be uploaded</param>
        /// <param name="relativeFolderPath">The relative Path to the Folder this Image resides in.</param>
        /// <param name="userId">A UserId</param>
        /// <param name="extension">The File Extension</param>
        /// <param name="token">A CancellationToken</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static File CreatePhoto(IFormFile file, string relativeFolderPath, Guid userId, FileExtension extension, CancellationToken token)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var photo = new Photo(userId);
            photo.SetFileProperties(file, relativeFolderPath, extension, token);

            return photo;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set Properties on File Entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">The File</param>
        /// <param name="relativeFolderPath">The Path extending from the WebRoot</param>
        /// <param name="extension">The File Extension</param>
        /// <param name="token">A CancellationToken</param>
        private void SetFileProperties(IFormFile file, string relativeFolderPath, FileExtension extension, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if(file == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(file));

            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relativeFolderPath))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(relativeFolderPath));

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            FileSize = (int) file.Length;

            Extension = extension;

            FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "." + extension.ToString().ToLower();

            FilePath = Path.Combine(relativeFolderPath, FileName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Extension of this File
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="extension"></param>
        /// <param name="ext">The Extension of the File</param>
        /// <param name="token">A CancellationToken</param>
        private static void FindExtension(string extension, out FileExtension ext, CancellationToken token)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            switch (extension.ToLower())
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    ext = FileExtension.Jpg;
                    break;

                case ".jpeg":
                    ext = FileExtension.Jpeg;
                    break;

                case ".png":
                    ext = FileExtension.Png;
                    break;

                case ".bmp":
                    ext = FileExtension.Bmp;
                    break;

                case ".gif":
                    ext = FileExtension.Gif;
                    break;

                case ".tif":
                    ext = FileExtension.Tif;
                    break;

                case ".tiff":
                    ext = FileExtension.Tiff;
                    break;

                case ".svg":
                    ext = FileExtension.Svg;
                    break;

                case ".doc":
                    ext = FileExtension.Doc;
                    break;

                case ".docx":
                    ext = FileExtension.Docx;
                    break;

                case ".odt":
                    ext = FileExtension.Odt;
                    break;

                case ".rtf":
                    ext = FileExtension.Rtf;
                    break;

                case ".txt":
                    ext = FileExtension.Txt;
                    break;

                case "xls":
                    ext = FileExtension.Xls;
                    break;

                case ".xlsx":
                    ext = FileExtension.Xlsx;
                    break;

                case ".ppt":
                    ext = FileExtension.Ppt;
                    break;

                case ".pptx":
                    ext = FileExtension.Pptx;
                    break;

                case ".pdf":
                    ext = FileExtension.Pdf;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new InvalidFileExtensionException($"The Extension {extension.ToLower()} is not allowed.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the Specified Extension is a allowed Extension.
        /// Returns true in case the extension is a file extension.
        /// Returns False in case the Extension is a Image File.
        /// The FileExtension Parameter is always set
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="extensionName">The extension as a string</param>
        /// <param name="extension">The Extension that this File has.</param>
        /// <param name="token">A CancellationToken</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsTextFile(string extensionName, out FileExtension extension, CancellationToken token)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            FindExtension(extensionName, out extension, token);

            return (int) extension > 8;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if the Extension is a allowed Extension and a Image File.
        /// the Extension will always be set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="extensionName">The Extension as string</param>
        /// <param name="extension">The FileExtension</param>
        /// <param name="token">A CancellationToken</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsImageFile(string extensionName, out FileExtension extension, CancellationToken token)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            FindExtension(extensionName, out extension, token);

            return (int)extension < 8;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And here is where my dilemma starts: When I try to apply a Code First Migration I get the following in the Migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Files",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    Created = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    LastModified = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    FileName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FilePath = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FileSize = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Extension = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Files", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Files_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Files_UserId",
                table: "Files",
                column: "UserId")
```

That should not happen as I only want to have my derived classes as Tables and not my Base Class. I already tried resolving it with the Ignore on Modelbuilder in my OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserRoleConfiguration());

    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserTokenConfiguration());

    builder.Ignore<File>();

    builder.Entity<User>().OwnsOne(x => x.FullName, fullName =>
    {
        fullName.OwnsOne(x => x.FirstName, firstName =>
        {
            firstName.Property(p => p.FirstNamePart).HasColumnName("FirstName_FirstPart").HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsRequired();
            firstName.Property(p => p.NameSeperator).HasColumnName("FirstName_NameSeperator").HasMaxLength(5);
            firstName.Property(p => p.LastNamePart).HasColumnName("FirstName_LastPart").HasMaxLength(255);
        });
        fullName.OwnsOne(x => x.LastName, lastName =>
        {
            lastName.Property(p => p.FirstNamePart).HasColumnName("LastName_FirstPart").HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsRequired();
            lastName.Property(p => p.NameSeperator).HasColumnName("LastName_NameSeperator").HasMaxLength(5);
            lastName.Property(p => p.LastNamePart).HasColumnName("LastName_LastPart").HasMaxLength(255);
        });
    });

    builder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
}
```

But the Output is still the same. Therefore I am asking how to resolve this, so I can have only the derived classes in the Database and not the abstract class.

I'm posting the Code you asked for here:

```
/// <summary>
/// The User of this Application.
/// </summary>
public class User : Entity<Guid>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Basic Constructor for the User
    /// </summary>
    public User()
    {
        UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
        UserClaims = new HashSet<UserClaim>();
        Tokens = new HashSet<UserToken>();
        Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();
        Files = new HashSet<TextFile>();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A Concurrency Stamp
    /// </summary>
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Email of this User
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Normalized Email of this User
    /// </summary>
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Flag that indicates if the User has Confirmed his Email.
    /// </summary>
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The User Name of this User.
    /// </summary>
    public string Username { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The normalized User Name
    /// </summary>
    public string NormalizedUsername { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The hashed and salted Password.
    /// </summary>
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Security Stamp to validate The Users Information
    /// </summary>
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Full Name of a User.
    /// </summary>
    public FullName FullName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The specific Y-Number that identifies the User 
    /// </summary>
    public string YNumberId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The YNumber of this User.
    /// </summary>
    public YNumber YNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Collection of Roles.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Collection of User Claims.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual  ICollection<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserToken> Tokens { get; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; }

    public virtual ICollection<TextFile> Files { get; }
}

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies all Configurations in this Assembly to the specified ModelBuilder Instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelBuilder">The Instance of the ModelBuilder that configures the Database.</param>
        public static void ApplyAllConfigurations(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var applyConfigurationMethodInfo = modelBuilder
                .GetType()
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .First(method => method
                    .Name
                    .Equals("ApplyConfiguration", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            var ret = typeof(ApplicationDbContext)
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Select(type =>
                    (type, i: type
                        .GetInterfaces()
                        .FirstOrDefault(i => i
                            .Name
                            .Equals(typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>)
                                .Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
                .Where(it => it.i != null)
                .Select(it => (et: it.i.GetGenericArguments()[0], configObject: Activator.CreateInstance(it.Item1)))
                .Select(it =>
                    applyConfigurationMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(it.et)
                        .Invoke(modelBuilder, new[] {it.configObject}));
        }
```

While checking my Code I had the Feeling that the error is not directly in the migration but in the Method that applies my Configuration. I am thinking that because the TextFile Class is not in the Db (I am trying to add it with this migration) and the Files Table that should be created has exaclty all Fiels of the TextFile Class. It is only named wrong. My Configuration for the TextFile class looks like this:

```
 public class TextFileConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TextFile>
    {

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TextFile> builder)
        {
            //Set Primary Key
            builder
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            //Add ValueGeneration
            builder
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

            //Set Table Name
            builder
                .ToTable("TextFiles");

            //Make Filename Required with MaxLength of 50 (because filename = Guid + FileExtension)
            builder
                .Property(x => x.FileName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            //Configure Inverse Navigation Property.
            builder
                .HasOne(x => x.User)
                .WithMany(y => y.Files)
                .HasForeignKey(z => z.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

Could it be that my Configuration just doesn't get applied?

Comment: Can't reproduce with the provided information, so the problem is somewhere else - ether the real models are different or there is some hidden code. There must be a reason for EF Core classifying your `File` class as **entity**. The first question should be where the `UserId` (and the FK to `Users`) is coming from - there is no such property in the shown `File` class.

Comment: Do you know a simple way to find out where EF Core is getting this from? I checked my files however they are exactly what I posted above

Comment: By some convention or code. For instance, does your `User` class contain something like `public ICollection<File>` property? Also what is `builder.ApplyAllConfigurations();` (should be some custom method probably using reflection - EF Core does not provide such a method)? May be there is some configuration which creates shadow property or says `modelBuilder.Entity<File>` etc. And btw, what exact EF Core version are you on (I've tested on the latest 2.1)?

Comment: I updated the Question with the Code you asked for and the Idea of what I think it could be. I am using Ef Core 2.1.4 with MSSQL as Provider. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well well well,

now after punishing myself for not reading my previous migrations precisely enough I am back to answering my Question:

I tried adding the following line directly into OnModelCreating:

```
builder.Entity<TextFile>().ToTable("Text Files");
```

and magic:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Text Files",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    Created = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    LastModified = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    FileName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FilePath = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    FileSize = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Extension = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Files", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Files_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Files_UserId",
                table: "Files",
                column: "UserId")
```

The Migration was right. Therefore I checked my ApplyConfiguration and realized it isn't applying any Configuration at all. Therefore I changed it to:

```
var implementedConfigTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract
                            && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition
                            && t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i =>
                                i.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>)));

            foreach (var configType in implementedConfigTypes)
            {
                dynamic config = Activator.CreateInstance(configType);
                modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(config);
            }
```

[Courtesy of this Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654500/apply-all-ientitytypeconfiguration-derived-classes-using-ef-core-2-0)

And thats applying now all Configurations, meaning I get the Correct Name and Amount of Fields for all Tables.

Thank you Ivan Stoev for trying to figure it out. Your Comment gave me the right hint.